# What is the difference between "py.test somepath" and "py.test --pyargs pkg"

Tags: pytest

I can't really understand the difference between these two.

1) py.test somepath # run all tests below somepath

2) py.test --pyargs pkg # run all tests found below directory of pypkg

For me, both of these are used to run all the test cases under a specified path.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only difference is `--pyargs` is convenient if you don't know the path to the package offhand, e.g. if you pip-installed it.